# How to split field and run sub query using it?

Tags: mysql, string-splitting

Given two tables T1 and T2 below, is there a way in MySQL 5.7.x to get such a list field from T1, so that none of its entries are present in T2?
T1.list is a regular VARCHAR, containing T2.vals delimited by ':'

From the example, I would like to get D:E field.

T1

```
id list
0  A:B:C
1  D:E
2  F:G
```

T2

```
vals
A
B
C
F
G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select t1.id, t1.list
from t1
left join t2 on locate(t2.vals, t1.list)
group by t1.id, t1.list
having 0 = count(t2.vals);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a095da8d2a93da85db22b436bd04515)

In more complex case (when a token in list may contain a token as a substring) you may use

```sql
select t1.id, t1.list
from t1
left join t2 on locate(concat(':',t2.vals,':'), concat(':',t1.list,':'))
group by t1.id, t1.list
having 0 = count(t2.vals);
```

Comment: If the delimiter were `,` instead of `:`, then `FIND_IN_SET()` could be handy.